# Flask/Jinja2 dynamic WTF form template

Tags: python, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am trying to create a jinaj2 template with a dynamic number of input fields.

The form is generating successfully in Flask, however I am having issues with the Jinja/HTML.

As an example of my "non-dynamic" working example I have one standard form field "forID" and  and four hard coded field forms field+(field number).

```
{{ form.csrf_token }}
{{ wtf.form_field(form.formID) }}

{{ wtf.form_field(form.field1) }}
{{ wtf.form_field(form.field2) }}
{{ wtf.form_field(form.field3) }} 
{{ wtf.form_field(form.field4) }}
```

What method can I use to make the Jinja/HTML dynamic. I have tried EVAL and EVEC, but these Python commands are not supported in Jinja.

```
#<form method="POST" action = "{{url_for('myHtmlTemplate')}}">
{{ form.csrf_token }}
{{ wtf.form_field(form.formID) }}

{% for i in form.myDynamicFields.keys() %}:
     {{ eval(' wtf.form_field(form.'+'i')') }}
{% endfor %}    

<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">
#</form>
```

My current myForm.

```
class myform(FlaskForm):
connection = removed
result = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM sqltable")
result = result.fetchall()

scenarioList = []
fieldList = []
fieldLabel = []

for scen in result:
scenarioList.append("Scenario: " + scen[0])
fieldList.append("field: " + scen[0])

for i in range(len(result)):
fieldLabel.append("My Field" + str(i + 1))

myDynamicFields = dict(zip(fieldLabel, fieldList))
formID = StringField('Form ID')

for key, val in myDynamicFields.items():
exec(key + '=StringField(val)')
```

Comment: You should show the code where you generate the form. What is `form.myDynamicFields`? If it's a dictionary, why can't you pass the value directly to the form_field method?

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you for a prompt response. "form" is an instance of myform, and I am struggling with Jinja to input form.(value from dictionary). In other languages I would use a dynamic field name, but I also think this is not available in Jinja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not manage to use the method of iterating the dictionary discussed above, although if it could work I agree it would be much more elegant.

However, I have a work around. Generating the HTML as a text string in my form instance, starting with a template and dynamically building up the section Jinja2 could not evaluate without errors. I pass this HTML string out the class into the render function.

In the meantime I’ll contact the Jinja2 development team to see how it could be done within the template itself.

Answer (score 1):

`' wtf.form_field(form.'+'i')'` has an odd number of apostrophes which is a syntax problem

I'm guessing you want something closer to:

```
' wtf.form_field(form.' + i + ')'
```

So that you get

```
i = 'your_field'
print(' wtf.form_field(form.' + i + ')')

wtf.form_field(form.your_field)
```

---

I do agree with @DanielRoseman's comment. I would probably approach the problem more like the following (if it works with your implementation):

```
{% for field in form.myDynamicFields %}:
     {{ wtf.form_field(field) }}
{% endfor %}
```